# TeamCity 8.0.5 Temporary ASP.NET Files compile error after McAfee 8.8 upgrade

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, teamcity, mcafee

We're using TeamCity 8.0.5 and compiling a very large Windows project which has many solutions and builds MVC apps.  We're using MSBuild 4.0 as the project runner on a Windows 2008R2 TeamCity Build Agent.  With McAfee 8.7.0, everything works fine.  After upgrading to McAfee 8.8, we see the following AspNetCompiler errors:

`MvcBuildViews
AspNetCompiler
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\temp\1884bd29\25991375\App_Web_fdee1qgl.1.cs(239, 0): error CS0433: The type 'ASP.ui_rds_datagrid_ascx' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\temp\1884bd29\25991375\App_Web_rds_datagrid.ascx.76ff77b3.jeh5fk3a.dll' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\temp\1884bd29\25991375\App_Web_rds_datagrid.ascx.76ff77b3.mtdxgue3.dll'`

I can verify that the problem occurs after installing McAfee 8.8 because when we revert to a VM snapshot prior to the upgrade, the project builds without error.
I tried running the project with the McAfee services stopped, but still get the same error.